# Set environment variable in grunt that is accessed in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gruntjs

I am initiating webpack from a `Gruntfile`.

If I have a task like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('start', ['browser', 'webpack-dev-server'], () => {
  // how do I set an environment variable?
});
```

How can I set some part of `env` so that it is accessible in webpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're executing webpack in your arrow function, you can set the environment variable on `process.env` first:

```
grunt.registerTask('start', ['browser', 'webpack-dev-server'], () => {
    process.env.SOME_VARIABLE = // ... some value here
    // ... execute webpack
});
```